# Find the centroid of a curve

Tags: geometry

**Problem:** Find the centroid of the part of the large loop of the limacon $r=1+2\cos(\theta)$ that does not include the small loop.

I know that in order to compute the centroid one needs to use following equations $$x=\frac{\iint_D xdydx}{m}$$ and $$y=\frac{\iint_D ydydx}{m},$$ where $$m=\iint_D dydx.$$ Note that we are assuming $\rho=1,$ which should work for this problem since I got the correct answer for a similar problem. The real issue that I am facing is that I am unable to set up the bounds on the integral because I do not what values of $r,\theta$ do I have to exclude in order to avoid the loop. Any help in this regard would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you write $m=x$? Also, this doesn't seem to be very Physics-related.

Comment: This is a pure mathematics question, it belongs on Mathematics SE.

Comment: @Noiralef I am sorry. Please see the edit.

Comment: @sammygerbil could you please transfer this question to MSE. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Note, for polar coordinates:
$$\textrm{d}x \textrm{d}y = \textrm{d}A = r \textrm{d}r \textrm{d}\theta ,$$ and $$x=r \cos{\theta} \textrm{ and } y=r \sin{\theta}.$$ Once you substitute those with proper bounds on $r$ and $\theta$ the rest is just integration.

Comment: Are these bounds correct $0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi$ and $0\leq r\leq 2$?

Comment: No. Those bounds give you the entire region inside the circle $r=2$. The maximum radius should always be the distance to the outer edge of limacon (different for each angle).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the answer to your problem is that the integration limits are $\theta\in [-2\pi/3,2\pi/3]$. I've gone ahead and solved the problem in the complex plane; you can compare results when you finish.

Given

$$
z=(2\cos\theta+1)e^{i\theta}\\
A=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-2\pi/3}^{2\pi/3}\Im\{z^*\dot z\}d\theta\\
Z_c=\frac{1}{3A}\int_{-2\pi/3}^{2\pi/3}z\ \Im\{z^*\dot z\}d\theta
$$

Notice that an advantage of the complex plane is that you have single integrals rather than doubles. At any rate, I find (with the help pf WolframAlpha) that

$$
A=\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}+2\pi\\
Z_c=\frac{\frac{27\sqrt{3}}{4}+8\pi}{3A}
$$

It's also true that the area and centroid are single integrals in polar coordinates, with

$$
x_c=\frac{\frac{1}{3}\int r^3\cos\theta d\theta}{\frac{1}{2}\int r^2 d\theta}\\
y_c=\frac{\frac{1}{3}\int r^3\sin\theta d\theta}{\frac{1}{2}\int r^2 d\theta}
$$